# Redirect wp-sitemap.xml not working

Tags: template-redirect, sitemap

I'd like to redirect `wp-sitemap.xml` to a custom sitemap file. I'm using `template_redirect` but the request isn't redirected. I attempted to debug it with `die()` but it doesn't work either.

```
function rh_redirect_wordpress_sitemap() {
    global $wp;
    
    if ( ! is_404() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $uri = $wp->request;
    
    if ( home_url( $uri ) == home_url( 'wp-sitemap.xml' ) ) {
        die( 'This is the WordPress sitemap' );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rh_redirect_wordpress_sitemap', 1 );
```

I've also disabled WordPress' sitemap.

```
add_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoast SEO uses the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` global to identify if it's a request to core sitemap, and then redirects from that.

Here's some untested code based off of Yoast's code:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    // If there is no path, nothing to do.
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $path = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );

    // If it's not a wp-sitemap request, nothing to do.
    if ( substr( $path, 0, 11 ) !== '/wp-sitemap' ) {
            return;
    }

    wp_redirect( 'https://example.com', 301 );
    exit;
} );
```

Source:
https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/d605e8ebdbcf14e7ad81215c0f9bd9ab0ea22451/src/initializers/disable-core-sitemaps.php#L69-L88

Comment: Thanks. As I understand it $wp->request performs a similar function as $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].